# Appending JSON file to HTML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json

The following code doesn't show the results.
I have tried this a couple of different things but I can't conclude whether it's my HTML, jQuery or JSON File (or all of the above) which is causing the problem.

```html
<div class="leaderboard">
  <div>
    <button id="try_this"> </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#try_this').click(function() {
    $('results.json').append('<select />');
    $('#results > span').each(function() {
      $('select').append('<option value="' + $(this).text() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</option>');
    });
  });
});
```

The JSON:

```
{
  "results": [{
    "Date": "October 28th",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Weather Conditions": "Sunny",
    "Time": 26.03,
    "Name": "Rachel Armstrong"
  }, {
    "Date": "October 28th ",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Weather Conditions": "Sunny",
    "Time": 29.33,
    "Name": "Christine Porter"
  }, {
    "Date": "October 28th ",
    "Gender": "Male ",
    "Weather Conditions": "Sunny",
    "Time": 31.41,
    "Name": "Keith Crawford"
  }, {
    "Date": "October 28th ",
    "Gender": "Male ",
    "Weather Conditions": "Sunny",
    "Time": 25.16,
    "Name": "Brian Burton"
  }, {
    "Date": "October 28th ",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Weather Conditions": "Sunny",
    "Time": 29.19,
    "Name": "Ruth Donelly"
  }]
}
```

Any nods in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see where you actually use the JSON...? How are you loading it in to the page? Via AJAX I presume?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeh, through Ajax is plan. I have t included a getJSON() method. That’s a start anyway.

Comment: Suggest you study some ajax tutorials

Answer (score 1):

With `$('results.json')`, jQuery will try to find an element of type `results` and with a class `json`.
You probably want to load the JSON using AJAX, so you would use something like:

```
$.getJSON('results.json', function(data) { ... });
```

And then here you use the `data` variable to create your elements.
For example you could use `data.results[0].Date`.